# Height between ListItem rows is too high

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI to create a list. My code below needs to reduce the height of the list element. I am not sure if it is padding or what. I tried setting  `<List dense={dense}>` but it is still too spaced out.

```
                  <ListItem
                    button
                    onClick={() => {
                      board.current.setPosition(fenHistory[index + 1]);
                      plyViewed = index + 1;
                    }}
                  >
                    <ListItemText
                      classes={{ primary: classes.listItemText }}
                      primary={game.history()[index]}
                    />
                  </ListItem>
```

The output current looks like the image below, but I want to reduce the height between the lines. Any ideas how?

[image: Height is too spread out]

Edit: Using the styling recommended in a reply, it is a little tighter now:

[image: Height better but still a little too high]

Answer (score 0):

You can override default styles like this:

```
<ListItem button style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 0 }}>
    <ListItemText primary={"sss"} style={{ lineHeight: 1, margin: 0 }} />
    <ListItemText primary={"sss"} style={{ lineHeight: 1, margin: 0 }} />
    <ListItemText primary={"sss"} style={{ lineHeight: 1, margin: 0 }} />
    <ListItemText primary={"sss"} style={{ lineHeight: 1, margin: 0 }} />
</ListItem>
```

Comment: That helped a little, thanks. I've pasted an additional imagine in my original post to show the difference. It is still a little too high though. I tried lineHeight of 0 but that didn't do much. What is leading to that excess space around the text?

Comment: @Jon you can also set ```margin: 0``` for ```ListItemText``` it's probably the littlest possible gap in this way. If you want less you probably should override classes like ```.MuiListItemText-root``` or ```.MuiListItemText-dense``` in your css files. Even though you set ListItemText line-height to 0 then still inside is ```span.MuiListItemText-root``` with ```line-heigh: 1.5```

Comment: Glad to hear. If you can accept the answer :)